# Linq Lookup using multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq

In my program, an item should only be created if the program determines that the item is not already contained within the collection.

Here is my code to read through. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
            foreach(var user in db.Gebruikers)
            {
                foreach(var parameter in db.ParametersWerkvorms)
                {
                    if(db.ZoekresultaatWerkvorms.Where(r => r.Werkvorm.Equals(parameter.Naam))) // ??????

// If user.username = db.ZoekresultaatWerkvorms.item.username && parameter.naam == db.ZoekresultaatWerkvorms.item.parameter{
                    var newItem = new ZoekResultaatParameter();
                    newItem.Parameter = parameter.Naam;
                    newItem.Opgezocht = 0;
                    newItem.Gebruikersnaam = user.Gebruikersnaam;
 // Write newItem to database
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using `.Where` returns an `IEnumerable` containing elements which pass the clause. You can check if this IEnumerable contains elements or not.

Comment: how come `if(db.ZoekresultaatWerkvorms.Where(r => r.Werkvorm.Equals(parameter.Naam))) // ??????` is not giving you any build error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, you need a `bool`.

Try something like: `if(db.ZoekresultaatWerkvorms.Any(r => r.Werkvorm.Equals(parameter.Naam)))`

Comment: Thank you, that works. :) Guess I could've used .length as well to match a boolean.